# A Generalization of Hadamard?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose that $F(x,y) = (f(x,y),g(x,y))$ is a polynomial map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume it is locally at most $k$-to-1. If the map $F(x,y)$ is $proper$, then Hadamard's Theorem shows that for $k=1$ the map is globally one-to-one.

What happens for $k=2$? Can we conclude anything about the global behavior of the map? Is it for example $k$-to-1?

Comment: The generalization you want is not of Hadamard *himself* but of his theorem, presumably!

Comment: Mariano: true, but surely I can't be the only person to sometimes say "by Cauchy-Schwarz" in informal settings?

Comment: Yes, you are not the only person who says "Cauchy-Schwarz" when should say "Bunyakovsky" :)

Comment: Anton: touch&eacute;. But then we are into the realms of arguing about Tychonov's theorem and the (Stone-)Cech compactification...

Comment: Yemon, while I indulge in the same usage, there is a bit of a difference; to say “by Cauchy–Schwarz” is to suggest that they are communicating to you the truth of the result, which one can accept metaphorically—the statement makes sense without identifying them with their inequality.  On the other hand, “a generalisation of Hadamard” can make sense *only* if we identify Hadamard with his theorem.

Comment: I apologize for getting the title wrong. I could not think of the right title.

Comment: There is no need of apologizing! It was just a silly remark of mine :)

Comment: I guess you know Stoilow's theorem (see p. 121 in his 1956 book Lecon sur les principes... or Google Stoilow's theorem)? If  $f$ is a discrete open mapping of the plane, then $f = P(h)$ with $h$ a homeomorphism of the plane 
onto a (simply connected) domain   
and $P$ an analytic function. There are some generalizations that relax the openness assumption (to allow folding, for example). 

Comment: Obviously Mariano was mostly joking, but I think the grammar in the title works fine; one frequently uses 'of' in the sense of 'owing to', e.g. the lemma of Schwarz (I think my professor used this form mostly because it was easier to say, frankly, but there is also a historical trend for that particular lemma).  We often leave the originator's name in theorems even if they were later generalized, as was indicated above with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (sorry Bunyakovsky).  Plus isn't it a bit poetic that Hadamard might exist through mathematics in some generalized way even after his death?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

$$
(x,y)\qquad\mapsto\qquad \Big(x^3-x,x^2\Big) + y^2\Big(-\frac{d}{dx}(x^2),\frac{d}{dx}(x^3-x)\Big)
$$

in other words:

$$
(x,y)\qquad\mapsto\qquad \big(x^3-x-2xy^2,x^2+(3x^2-1)y^2\big)
$$

I think that this is an exmple of a map that is locally (in the source) 2-to-1, but not globally 2-to-1.

Comment: Can you tell what it is globally? Is it k to 1 for some k?

Comment: The singular locus (in the target $\mathbb R^2$) of this map is parametrized by the curve $x \mapsto (x^3-x,x)$. It is a nodal cubic. That nodal cubic splits the plane into three regions: two unbounded and one bouded. A point in the interior of the bounded region has no preimage. A point in the interior of the region adjacent to the bounded one has two preimages. A point in the interior of the third region has four preimages.